# Asynchronous progress updates in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC3, and I have a long-running task I have a user kick off, but I'd like for the user to receive feedback of what is going on, in case something unexpected happens.

I know MVC3 supports asynchronous controllers, but it does not seem that this communicates very well with the spawned thread, so sending updates through seems messy.  I was wondering if there was a standard technology or methodology for providing this sort of feedback or if I would need to home-grow something.

Comment: It sounds like you're after a more persistent connection.  Have you looked into SignalR(https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)?  It's .NET and handles persistent connections.

Comment: Take a look at the SignalR library, it might be what you're looking for.